# Disable AJAX in a form

Tags: forms

I need to disable AJAX proccessing for a multiple value field in forms.

Can somebody tell me how to disable it?

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? You want to rewrite forms so they would not need ajax? Or you want to simply make ajax fail?

Comment: @Mołot I use field collection module and when I have about 7+ items and I try do add new one the ajax request froze the browser. I check that it works pretty well if I disable javascript in my browser so I suppose I need to disable the ajax in that form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax behavior is attached to form elements when there is a record in `Drupal.settings.ajax` for the HTML-id of the form element. Therefore in order to disable Ajax for a given form-element, you need to remove the appropriate ajax settings record. You can achieve that by implementing `hook_js_alter`:

```
function hook_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  foreach ($javascript['settings']['data'] as $index => $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $settings) {
      if ($key == 'ajax') {
        // The prefix id for a field_collection with the name fc:
        $field_id_prefix = 'edit-field-fc-und';

        // Remove ajax settings for the "Add another item" button
        unset($javascript['settings']['data'][$index][$key][$field_id_prefix . '-add-more']);

        // If you also need to de-ajaxify the "Delete" buttons:
        foreach (array_keys($settings) as $element_id) {
          if (preg_match('/' . $field_id_prefix . '-[0-9]+' . '-remove-button/', $element_id)) {
            unset($javascript['settings']['data'][$index][$key][$element_id]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```