# Is it possible to turn off Ajax load for Commerce Coupon Module?

Tags: commerce, ajax

I am getting a bunch of issues with the [Commerce Coupon module 7.x-2.0-rc3](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_coupon). Mainly there are inconsistencies with the forms updating and also intermittent timeouts. I'm assuming it's an Ajax load issue.

Is there a way to turn off the Ajax load when a coupon is applied, and just get a regular page load?

[image]

Comment: Your question is very unspecific, we would need to see the error. Disabling AJAX would be the last option to me, and could be done via altering the corresponding form. I saw they just relased rc4 yesterday. try to update first !

Comment: The issue happens when on a single page checkout. It fixes it when i move the payment method to a separate page. It has to do with Ajax not refreshing the page correctly when on a single page. Which is why i would like to opt for a regular full page load rather than a partial Ajax page load.

Is there a setting to turn off Ajax or is the module hard coded with Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you run into this bug https://www.drupal.org/node/2412549.

Apply the two patches mentioned in comment #9

> If you really want to turn of AJAX, you need to hook all the
>   corresponding forms and unset #ajax.

**i would not suggest this thoe !**

Comment: Thanks, i saw this but am in production and didnt want to switch modules out. Is there a way to just turn off Ajax load for the module? this would probably solve the issue? I'm not sure why it is an Ajax load and not a normal page load

Comment: It's not so easy to turn AJAX off, and commerce heavily relies on AJAX, so i would not recommend it ...

Answer (score 0):

The site is in production, but it is broken at the moment. I would advise :

1. Disable the faulty module, for a while, so that the site continues to run and people are not seeing a mess.
2. using `drush ard`, get a an archive of the current site and run it locally.
3. Check what modules you can update related to the commerce layer, especially coupons and shipping. Do this one by one and look at when your problem is solved.
4. Do the same update directly on prod with : `drush up module_name1 module_name2` (If you don't have command line access you are good with the normal upgrade process from the backend also)
5. Special advise : you should use this opportunity to update also all modules with a security alert after have tested offline if this doesn't break anything.
6. As mentioned by rémy, disabling ajax is likely to be very hazardous, however it is possible to do that on specific modules, and for this you can refer to [Disable AJAX in a form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87638/disable-ajax-in-a-form)